# Levitating Magnet Experiment

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, levitation

i want to make a levitating device with magnets.
now i have some ideas but i don't know the math to work the numbers out. here is what is want to do :

[image: what i want to do]

so the idea is basically to lift a device (about 50 grams) to 5 cm above the base. but the lifting must be smooth and stable. in other words it must be easy to place the device on top of the base and it must not move off the base with small flick. problem is i don't know what magnets to use inside base magnet or the top magnet. i did some reading about magnetic fields and lenz's law and came up with this plan which seems to provide a stable field but i don't know if it is possible in a 20*20 cm base :

[image]

what method will provide my needs and also is possible ?
and info about magnet dimensions would be appreciated.

sorry for my bad English. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to make levitation with permanent magnets. Look for Earnshaw's theorem. You would need some sort of system with electrical magnet + sensor to actively control the levitation.